# How to safe remove an external usb hd ntfs?

Tags: windows-8.1, external-hard-drive, filesystems, usb-storage

I did format a hitachi 300GB external HD in NTFS with two partitions, primary and logic. My intention os to use one for "trash" and other as backup of my notebook with Windows 8.1. But after I connect it by usb port, the EJECT option does not show up. Should be at bottom right corner where usually I safe remove pendrive. In file manager it does not appears too, as it was an internal HD.

I'm aware that I REALLY should not remove this unit without unmounting it because of the way NTFS works. In my Mac it appears as any other removable media, I just right click on it and eject. In Windows 8.1 I have to open Device Manager and deactivate the unit (and when plug in again I have to activate it to be mounted).

How can I make this processes less painful in windows 8.1?

Comment: NTSC (Television system) != NTFS (File system). "In file manager it does not appears too" - What does this mean? How do you use it if it doesn't appear in File Explorer? "I'm aware that I REALLY should not remove this unit without unmounting it because of the way NTSC works." - You can always set the drive's properties to optimize for quick removal which will disable the write cache.

Comment: WTF! Thanks, I did the correction! I was feeling strange about this post already...

Comment: In file explorer, there is a list of units. When I plug in a pendrive, right-clicking on it opens some options as eject - so I can eject (unmount). It is already set as "quick remove".

Comment: If it's optimized for quick removal then you should be able to yank it out without data loss. So the drive doesn't show up in the Safely Remove Hardware menu? If that's the case it's being detected as a fixed instead of removable disk. What sort of enclosure did you use to convert the internal HDD into a USB HDD? That enclosure is responsible for this behaviour.

Comment: I used Mac OS X Disk Utility to first format it, with Tuxera drivers. After, Mini Tool Partition Wizzard to create the two partitions.

Comment: Why not format it in Windows rather than on a Mac with a reverse-engineered NTFS driver? Anyway that's not what I asked. You said "it was an internal HD". So what sort of enclosure/case did you use to convert it to an external USB HDD?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 has a tray icon for *Safely Remove Hardware and Eject Media*, [image], that should remove the drive even when the *Eject* context menu item is not available. This can also be done from *Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Devices and Printers*: right-click on the device and select *Remove device*.

If the tray icon is not visible, you might need to "customize the taskbar".

Comment: Hey, you nailed it, I had the wrong idea that you needn't eject these are they don't offer eject in the context menu.  Good to know, thanks!